# Code using dynamic import is also part of webpack bundle in React project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, dynamic-import

I am using the following code:

```
const image = React.lazy(() => import('../../../images').then(({ errorImage }) => ({ default: permissionErrorImage })));
        return (
            <div>
                <img
                    src={image.name}
                    className="error-image"
                />
            <div>    
        );
```

I am checking bundle size using webpack bundle analyzer and it's the same when normal import is used and when dynamic import is used.

Comment: Post more of your code. It looks like the dynamic import and rendering of the component are in the body of a functional component or render...? Are you using React.Suspense...?

Comment: @jered Yes. I have kept dynamic import and rendering in a functional component. I am not using React.Suspense